# How do use a template object of any type

Tags: c++

Code changed below to use smart pointers:

I have a template class:

```
class IRequest;
template<class T>
class Request : public IRequest
{
public:
   Request(T in) : m_data(in) {}
   virtual ~Request() {}
   T get() { return m_data; }
   void set(T in) { m_data = in; }
private:
   T m_data;
}
```

In another class I have the methods:

```
template<T>
void invoke(Request<T>& request)
{
   // Do some stuff
}
std::unique_ptr<IRequest> getRequest(int which)
{
   switch(which)
   {
   case 1:  return std::unique_ptr<IRequest>(new Request<int>(1));
   case 2:  return std::unique_ptr<IRequest>(new Request<bool>(true));
   case 3:  return std::unique_ptr<IRequest>(new Request<double>(2.0));
   default: throw std::exception();
   }
}
void run()
{
   int type = getRequestType();
   std::unique_ptr<IRequest> request = getRequest(type);
   invoke(*request);
}
```

The problem is this, the run() method cannot be templated, there must be only 1 or them,
and it needs to be able to deal with any type of request it receives, as getRequestType()
is reading the value from a file, which can contain any type.

The compiler does not like this, it expects Request to have a type in angled brackets,
both in the run() method, and for the call to invoke(). It also expects the return type
of getRequest() to have angled brackets.

Is there a C++ mechanism for holding and passing around a template object of any type?

Using a smart pointer should the invoke stay as it is, or should it change to:

```
void invoke<IRequest& request)
```

Comment: A common mistake of trying to use run-time data in compilation phase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no.  `Request<int>` and `Request<double>` are different types and `Request` by itself is not a type.  Your `getRequest` method is not valid as you are returning different types in the different cases.

One method to work around this is to have a base class that `Request` inherits, e.g. `IRequest`.  You could then return a (smart) pointer to a `IRequest` in your getRequest method.

Note that you won't be able to call the current methods in your templated class as you cannot specify them as virtual functions in the base class.  You could however move your invoke method to your base class as a pure virtual function, allowing it to be implemented in the templated class.

```
class IRequest
{
public:
  virtual ~IRequest() { }
  virtual void invoke() = 0;
};


template <typename T>
class Request : public IRequest
{
public:
  Request(T in) : m_data(in) { }
  virtual ~Request() { }
  virtual void invoke() { /* Do stuff */ }

private:
  T m_data;
};
```

Comment: Does this base class require any implementation, can I just do "class Interface;" then "class Request : public Interface" then have getRequest() return a std::unique_ptr<Interface>?

Comment: Added a note about virtual methods in the base class.  As mentioned by John Zwinck, moving the invoke method to your base class is known as the Visitor Pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Boost Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/variant.html) for this.  It will let you declare not just a single type of Request that can be returned, but a specific, limited set of them.  Or you might decide to have your Request contain a variant internally, rather than being a templated type itself.

Alternatively, you could make Request have a virtual base and implement the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an abstract class `IRequest`, which is not a template class, and make your template class extend it.

You will have then to change the signature of the method to:

```
IRequest& getRequest(int which)
```

And similary, change `Request` in `run()` and `invoke()` to `IRequest&`.

You will also have to make sure the memory for the object is dynamically allocated, instead of automatic allocation.

Comment: Note that returning a reference would mean you have to store the object somewhere, and that is must live for at least as long as it is being used by the caller.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thank you for pointing that out. My C++ is a bit rusty, but as far as I see it, this cannot be avoided, you must return a reference (or a pointer) - since you otherwise invoke the wrong copy constructor, and lose data (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Returning a smart pointer with clear ownership semantics would be an option. In this case, `std::unique_ptr<IRequest>` seems to match the use-case best.